# Email and username validation not working in yii2

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I have a form with lot of fields including username and email. I also put some validation rules into the relevant model. When I submit the form I want to show the result `"username already exist"` if that email address is already present in the system.

I'm using:

```
[['email'], 'unique']
```

But when I submit with already existing record it doesn't show the validation error.

When I comment
  `[['user_name', 'full_name', 'password', 'email', 'address1', 'address2', 'city', 'state', 'country', 'zip', 'phone', 'card_number'], 'required']`

rule everything works fine.

Comment: give email unique in your database table

Comment: i want to print that on screen if email and username already exist in database.

Comment: i am writing code below try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally got it.actually their is no problem.ajax validation didn't happen for username and email .when we fill all other field and submit leaving username and email . validation work and  alert us "credentials  already exist "